# Netbeans a new window for each project

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-8

I have 2 projects inside of netbeans. I would like to open to windows, one for each project. Is this possible within netbeans 8.1? I have googled the question and the response show no, but the answers are all older (~3 - 10 years old). Is it yet possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

NetBeans uses a concept of user directory and one user directory corresponds to one IDE window.  Multiple projects can be opened in one NetBeans IDE Window, but if you need multiple NetBeans IDE windows, the only way to do that is to use two different user directories.

To open a new NetBeans IDE window you can start the NetBeans application from command prompt by providing a command line parameter `--userdir` followed by an existing blank directory.  NetBeans will use this directory as a user directory and will open another IDe window, where you can open your another project

More details can be read [here](http://netbeans.tusharjoshi.com/2008/12/opening-multiple-netbeans-ide-instances.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes this is what I was looking at older blogs and was hoping there would be an easier way now, but it looks like this is the only way. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just checked it out in my 8.0.2 and all you have to do is open the classes from each separate project and then drag them to the side of Netbeans which will show you how it will be positioned and you can have the two classes side by side. You can then continue to open classes from each project and keep them on which ever side you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think we are talking about different things. I am not trying to make the classes side by side, I am trying to open two complete separate Windows for each project.

Comment: Minimize your netbeans and drag the class outside of the netbeans window will generate a new window for your class.

Answer (score 0):

I know its probably too late bt im using netbeans 10, just drag a frame or class outside the netbeans idea and it creates a new window.